# Select logic changed with latest versions - product resource collection

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, product-collection

While performing an upgrade of a Magento 1 shop, noticed a change in core class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`, within method `_initSelect`

The change that has happened is, that condition :

```
->columns(array('status' => new Zend_Db_Expr(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)));
```

has been replaced with :

```
->where('e.status = ?', new Zend_Db_Expr(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
```

Does anyone knows the reasoning behind this change, and what could be the problems if I decide to revert to original version ? I'm asking this because, due to this change, some custom listing pages have started to throw following error now :

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status' in 'where clause'

Comment: I dont know the reason for, but i guess it is to avoid "ambiguous column" problems, when joining other tables. I'd try to leave it and fix custom pages instead